# Does there exist such a sequence?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, number-theory

Does there exist a infinite sequence of positive integers $a_n$. Such that $ ((n|a_n) | \forall n)$ and $\left(\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac {1}{a_n} =1\right)$ , what if we replace 1 with a positive real number r ?

if we weaken $\left(\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac {1}{a_n} =1\right)$  to $\left(\sum_{n\in S} \frac{1}{a_n} =1\right)$  for some infinite subset $S$ of naturals. We have an example $S = (2^n |n\in \Bbb N)$ and $(a_n=n)$ , Can we classify all such examples? Are there infinitely many?

What if $S$ is finite? We have the example $S=(2,3,6)$ and $(a_n = n)$ i.e. $\left(\frac 12 +\frac 13 +\frac 16 = 1\right)$ , So what are all such examples? Certainly there are infinitely many, as we can multiply each term in the finite sum $\left(\frac 12 +\frac 13 +\frac 16 \right)$ by $\left(\frac 12\right)$ and add $\left(\frac 12\right)$ to get 1, and repeat the process.

What happens if we weaken $( (n|a_n ) |(\forall n))$ to $( (n|a_n )| (\forall n>n_0))$ for some $n_0$?

Comment: I'm sure the answer to the first question is yes, by a greedy algorithm --- at each stage, take $a_n$ to be the smallest multiple of $n$ that keeps the sum under $1$.

Comment: oops that was silly but serious! i couldn't find those before.

Comment: It looks much better now!

Answer (score 3):

> Does there exist a infinite sequence of positive integers $a_n$ such that $ ((n|a_n) | \forall n)$ and $\left(\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac {1}{a_n} =1\right)$

$a_n = n(n+1)$.

> if we weaken $\left(\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac {1}{a_n} =1\right)$  to $\left(\sum_{n\in S} \frac{1}{a_n} =1\right)$  for some infinite subset $S$ of naturals.

A necessary condition is that the sum of $1/n$ restricted to $S$ is at least $1$.

When $S$ is finite the problem falls under the name "Egyptian fractions" and more information can be found by searching on that term.

Comment: nice answer!, i was too dumb to not think of that , what happens if we replace 1 with a arbitrary positive real number r ?

Comment: Gerry Myerson's argument in the comments works.

Comment: ya it seems to work!, What about sufficient condition for infinite subset S of N ? will the Gerry Myerson's argument work? i am just waiting for complete answer, thats why i removed the tick mark,

Comment: It should not be hard to figure out if the greedy algorithm always works when $S$ is infinite and the sum of elements in $1/S$ is greater than or equal to the target value $r$.  If it does, that is the answer, and if not, I expect that there is no nice condition.